# Docker taking forever to restart after changing image location

Tags: docker, window

I am trying to use Docker desktop on Windows, and change the image location to my second hard drive instead of the system drive, however, when I click apply and restart, Docker desktop start to run forever and I'm not sure if anything is happening. Is there a way to change that in the command line so I can check any logs?